# I am getting error in c++ programm while using log4cxx

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I am getting error in c++ program while using log4cxx. The error message is:

```
error:Please initialize the log4cxx system properly
```

Please help to resolve,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR you have to configure the log4cxx system at the beginning of your program, e.g. using a `BasicConfigurator` as shown in this [Short introduction to Apache log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html):

```
#include "log4cxx/logger.h"
#include "log4cxx/basicconfigurator.h"
#include "log4cxx/helpers/exception.h"

using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

LoggerPtr logger(Logger::getLogger("MyApp"));

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
  BasicConfigurator::configure();

  LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, "Entering application.");
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

HTH
Martin